# How can I prevent griefers from grabbing all my loot in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

Each time I have 8 diamonds, the griefer keeps grabbing my valuable loot. How can I keep my stuff safe so that the griefers can't find it? Should I use redstone tools? Should I make a hidden place where I can see my loot and the griefer can't find it?

Comment: What server are you playing on?

Comment: Unless this is an anarchy-style server, or a small one, then your best solution is to ask an admin who accessed your chest and then to get them banned. Most large servers will have a plugin that lets them do that.

Comment: Stop making friends with people who have Youtube channels, those dudes always love to grief and post it on their channel :P.

Comment: Nice suggestions so far! Keep up the suggestions.

Comment: There is no "the griefer" in Minecraft. Unless you were playing on a multiplayer server, and if you are, you should state so. Please, be more specific.

Comment: @NelsonStargamer I'm just pinging you here to notify that I have vastly updated my answer, combined it with new ideas and added screenshots, and I'd be very happy if you took the time and read it. Thanks!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The Ender Chest is the best approach, but if you don't want/can't use an Ender chest there, here are some solutions I have prevented theft in Minecraft.

## Redstone Traps

I have in the past created a storage room with tons of trapped chests, ~25% of which were "real" and the other ~75% killed everyone in the room. Fall damage is the best in my opinion, because it is hard to prevent once that trap is triggered, enables you to collect the thief's items, and your own items aren't destroyed if you trigger your own trap. Lava takes time, and the thief can break/get out, and his items are destroyed. Don't use TNT because that destroys your items. This usually only works once though, and trapped chests are suspicious. I like this approach because I am a Redstone kind of person, and I like the challenge of creating red stone traps for the thieves.

## Hiding Your Chests

Obtain stone blocks. Go down into your mine. Mine 5 blocks down. Place chests and valuables. Write down coordinates. Place 5 stone blocks above. Tell no one that you even hid a chest. This method has always worked for me, and it is cheap.

## Having the item in your inventory

Items in your inventory can't be stolen when you are offline. They can kill you, but you will know who did it, and can talk to them/take revenge depending on your situation. I like storing all my valuable diamond armor on me. Swords too.

As a side note, I usually never have all my diamonds in one spot. I distribute my diamonds among chests, and when a thief is successful, they usually leave after they steal one set of diamonds.

Comment: If you go down the lava pit route, making it a long fall and lining the sides with obsidian can make it very much more difficult to survive the trap.

Comment: Thanks Grant Davis for the method! Although it does sound cheap! Yours is my favorite because I don't need an ender chest so that I don't have to break it at all.

Comment: Glad I could help. I have seen alot of good servers become unpopular due to theft.

Comment: Having faced down griefers, this doesn't work.

Comment: also bear in mind that anyone with x-ray vision mods may be able to see which chests have traps and also where hidden chests may be hidden

Comment: Man, I don't play minecraft, but all of this really makes me wonder why anyone would ever play on a server with people other than those they personally know/trust to not be a dick.

Comment: Usually there are public, or semi-public where you have to write a paragraph about why you want to join, where random users can join. More private MC servers, such as servers where at you have to know someone who is already on are good. Also forum servers or servers where there is a good amount of communication outside the game I have also usually good. Even ad little communication as an stack exchange chat room can keep a server good, usually.

Comment: Basically servers with communication, good community, and knowledge of people before they join significantly improve the stability of the server and significantly lessen the griefers. I have seen good semi-public server last a long time, and I did fine with the tricks above. I have searched for public vinilla MC servers, but they get full of griefers quickly.

Comment: @lasagne- You can encase the chest in lava/coal ore (see my answer) to prevent "hackers" seeing it :)

Answer (score 33):

You can use an Ender Chest to store things that you don't want stolen. The contents of the chest are unique to the person opening it, so a potential griefer won't see anything that they haven't put in themselves.

The recipe for an Ender Chest is as follows:

[image: Crafting recipe for an Ender Chest showing 8 blocks of Obsidian arranged in a square with an Eye of Ender in the middle]

<sup>Image courtesy of [MinecraftXL](http://www.minecraftxl.com/wiki/ender-chest/)</sup>

There are a few important things to note about Ender Chests:

- They do not drop their contents when broken like regular chests do
- Every Ender Chest shares the same inventory, so while this means you can access the contents from any Ender Chest anywhere in the game the amount of available space is *extremely* limited
- Ender Chests require a **Silk Touch** pickaxe to pick up without destroying them
- Unlike standard chests they cannot be joined together to increase their capacity
- You cannot share their contents with another player, so if you need to do this an Ender Chest is not appropriate

---

If Ender Chests don't meet your requirements for whatever reason then you're going to have to look at alternative solutions such as physically hiding the chest that your valuables are stored in. The most important thing to remember about this approach however is this:

*If **you** can access the chest then so can any potential thief!*

This means that there is *no guaranteed method* of securing a regular chest against griefers, all you can do is make it unreasonably difficult for them to gain access to it.

If you're the server host you can also get mods such as Lockette or Light Weight Chest Protection that allow you to make chests private, but that's potentially a quite heavy-handed solution and might not be the right thing for you.

Comment: One thing to note about hiding the chest is that griefers frequently have access to x-ray tools and chest-highlighting tools, and these quickly defeat the purpose of any physical camouflage unfortunately. Great answer!

Comment: @DaimyoKirby (also pinging the OP): I don't want to sound overly self-advertising here, but my answer provides a solution to the problem you mentioned :)

Answer (score 18):

###Hide your items cleverly

> Disclamer: Xray is used for demonstrational purposes here. This kind of cheating is bannable! Do not try this at home! We are what people call professionals. That means that we tried it at least 3 times.

Hiding your items at a randomly placed chest underground will protect your items **only partially**; cheaters may use mods/texture packs/hacks (generally called "Xrays") to see through walls and find your chest(s). For example, this is how a randomly placed chest, as other answers state, seen by xrayers:

[image]

But if you hide your container at the proper place, it won't get revealed:

- **In Lava:**
- it is opaque; it can't be seen through. Ideally, [place your storage under a natural lava pool/cave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dpxz7.jpg). Also, nobody will run around checking around lava pools for diamonds.
- **Encased in cheap resources:**
- [encase your storage with iron/coal ore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAfOi.png). Cheaters usually go for chests (loot), diamonds (loot) and people's livings (more loot), not for coal.
- **At a very low level**: Place your storage [as low into the bedrock layers as possible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B61yj.png), then [enclose it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBlCH.png) with lava/coal/iron/all at once

---

###But wait! What about chest highliter mods/hacks, which show you where the closest chests are?

Well, this one is simple: **Don't place your items in a *chest***. Use clever containers, like:

- Droppers (up to 9 stacks of items)
- **Hoppers (up to 5 stacks)**. Plus, [hoppers blend in with Bedrock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZ3ef.png) and [aren't usually visible with xrays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDPQp.png)
- Furnaces (up to 2 stacks)
- Donkeys or Minecarts (up to 27 stacks)

Using Hoppers is the safest option, for multiple reasons (same color as bedrock, not entities, usually filtered out by xrays)

---

###Combine with other answers!

I combined the methods and tips from other answers (mainly my own). Here's how to keep your items safe:

1. Find a cave flooded with lava as it isn't transparent - blocks x-rays, as seen below.

[image]

But that still isn't good enough! People can turn off lava visibility!

[image]

Well, yeah. Then your storage is visible. The next step solves it, though.

1. Dig under it, and fill it's floor with some cheap resource, preferably Coal Ore - blocks x-rays if lava is "turned off":

[image]

Here's shown how I hid it (with part of the coal uncovered):

[image]

Wait, what if they have Lava *and* Coal ore turned off, as in the image below?

[image]

1. Find a remote place in between bedrock blocks under the lava.
2. Craft many [Shulker boxes](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Shulker_Box) and put your items inside (optional step)
3. Hide your items, by one of the following methods:

- Craft a pair (or more) ender chests; Place one down and put your items inside. Optionally place one ender chest to your hiding place.
- Place a hopper in your remote area and place your items inside.(Recommended by own experience. Xrays track Ender Chests more often.)

To sum up the 3 steps described above, here is how your hopper/ender chest hiding should look like from up close and from afar:

[image]

[image]

1. Add a few blocks of Lava above it to prevent accidental finding, and if, to possibly kill the finder. On the following image, a hopper is placed just diagonally (down to the right) from the lava:

[image]

1. Why not use a chest anyways? They'll find the storage if they turn off Bedrock, Lava and Coal ore at once. Then it's pretty obvious, whatever the storage you have.

[image]

How to deal with this? Well, chances are, the potential robber will have hoppers also off, because it isn't a useful block to keep non-transparent:

[image]

---

**TL;DR: Place your items in a hopper under/in a big pool of lava at one of the lower bedrock layers.**

Comment: Very thorough, useful screenshots - great answer! It's all definitely a big tradeoff between security and convenience, just like in real life.

Answer (score 6):

At the new 1.11 update there's an Shulker box. It's a pocket chest so you can hold it in your Ender chest. Nobody will be able to get your stuff. Actually if you have 27 shulker boxes, they will fit 1 enderchest. So that means every slot have another 27 slots. That makes 702 (27X27-27 because you will not use 27 slots of them.

Also try putting the enderchest in a hopper, as @GrantDavis said, 5 blocks under the mine stairs.

**EDIT:** Thanks again to @GrantDavis, yes, it needs **Silk touch pickaxe to break.**

Comment: This requires a silk touch pickaxe to pick up the ender chest once you use it.

Answer (score 3):

Besides the Ender Chest (which the griefer might just cut apart for obsidian), there is only one other solution that actually works against griefers. The problem is the advanced griefers use X-ray mods that reveal the traps. The only solution I could find is hide where they won't think to search.

Comment: The griefer might break the Ender Chest, but that means you just need to make a new one - it doesn't let them take whatever was inside it

Comment: @JonK: True, but that means you need to obtain more diamonds first which takes awhile. I prefer to not keep diamonds in main inventory.

Comment: Ender Chests don't need diamonds to make, just 8 Obsidian and an Eye of Ender. Although I grant you that it does stop you accessing whatever was in the Ender Chest until you replace it. But I always carry a spare one with me so that I can access it anywhere.

Comment: Don't worry! I am the owner and I have a few servers but I am not revealing it because it is my private servers with my friends. Anyways, I can just prevent hacks with admin plugins because I am the owner in my private servers. I can just ban them and just detect with coding and a lot of stuff, I am not going to mention the coding anyways, Also I can just put the server to white-list so that the server won't be insanely destroyed.

Comment: @NelsonStargamer If you're the server owner you might want to look at getting some mods in that can protect chests - they're designed to prevent exactly this kind of griefing. That does greatly depend how confident you are that you can install said mods though.

Comment: Also items kept in your inventory are safe when offline.

Comment: @GrantDavis: Correct; and they're vulnerable to server lag when online (oops where did that lava come from ...).

Comment: @NelsonStargamer Some servers place a publicly accessible Ender Chest in the protected spawn zone.

Comment: @Random832: Now that's awesome.

Answer (score 2):

If it is something rare but you don't have much of it, you could hide it in a hidden area in an item frame. You can fit four in one block, and you can put it anywhere. You could try a ender chest, so even if they find it they cant get your items (You will need to create a new chest to get your items back, but they are not gone!).

Comment: Interesting idea with the item frames, although it's fairly space-inefficient and time-consuming to get the items back out of them again.

Comment: Yeah, great idea! XRayers aren't looking for item frames so :D

Answer (score -2):

Just use an Ender Chest. Like everybody else said, just make another one if a greifer destroys it

Comment: This doesn't add anything else that other answers don't cover, as you observed yourself with "Like everybody else said".

Comment: That's good, I guess

Comment: thats all i could think of :/ im on xbox, so i dont go onto servers, so idk much about it. Thats all i could suggest :/ P.S. why did i lose **ALL** of my reputation? >:(